# Showing huge GIS data on map using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, large-datasets

I have a huge amount of GIS data in a database. I am fetching this data and converting it into GeoJSON before viewing the map. I am fetching all of the data to meet the requirements, which is taking a lot of time. Is there any way to load data for a particular map window which user is viewing, and only loading respective GIS data for the same window using the Leaflet library?

In my case, I am using Google Maps to show parking slots (GIS data) of a country on a map.

Comment: Please merge your two accounts ASAP using these instructions: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts  This appears to be another account of yours: https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88776/ashiwandre

Answer (score 6):

In an Ideal condition, if you have lots of Data, you do not add it to the Map as a GeoJSON, since :

- It will be a Large File, and hence will take a long time for  the client to receive in its browser over the internet.
- This large amount of data will consume a lot of resources when Leaflet will draw it in the browser.

This kind of problem can usually be solved by using some kind of server side rendering.

- You can use a GIS server like GeoServer to serve out this data as a WMS service.
- You could use some other technology like MapBox or CartoDB to serve this data as Vector Tiles.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient workflow recommendation depends on the type of database you have.

For example, w/ PostGIS you would probably want to create vector tiles dynamically. You could then consume this endpoint in Leaflet using the (Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile) library: https://github.com/spatialdev/PGRestAPI/blob/master/docs/VectorTiles.md

Note: dynamic vector tile endpoints pulling from PostGIS only pulls the geometry column, and the resulting .pbf (vector tile) will contain NO properties/attributes.

You could also defer to a tile rendering tool, such as Tippecanoe. In order to use this tool you would simply:

Step 1. Install tippecanoe w/ homebrew.

Step 2. Build vector tileset from collection of GeoJSON features w/ $ tippecanoe -o file.mbtiles [file.json ...]

Step 3. Import to SQLite database or upload to Mapbox Studio.

Step 4. use Mapbox.js, a Leaflet plugin, that "extends Leaflet functionality with additional code to integrate with Mapbox services and your data on Mapbox."

Note: the default Mapbox.js file includes a copy of Leaflet pinned to a particular stable version. If you want just Mapbox.js and to use your own local copy of Leaflet, go to this page to grab the standalone URLs:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/standalone/

Comment: Keep in mind with PGRestAPI you can include additional fields in the url string as options.